# Open Firefox Developer Tools on certain display

Tags: display, firefox

When I hit the inspect button on a website, Firefox (developer edition, on display 1) opens the developer tools on display 3 (I have three monitors). Is there a way to tell Firefox (or Mac) to open the developer tools on display 2?

Comment: Are all 3 monitors in a single, shared Space, or do they have separate Spaces/Desktops?

Comment: They have separate desktops!

Comment: You can do this reliably only if they're all the same Space/Desktop, because Apps are not designed to be set to more than one Space.